# How to display particular array of items from a database (SQLServer) in a Spinner of Android?

Tags: android

How can I display a particular array of items from a database (SQLServer) in a Spinner of Android?

Answer (score 7):

You provide data to your `Spinner` by way of a [`SpinnerAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html).  The adapter can be backed by a simple array, or by a database cursor, or whatever you like...

If you really mean Microsoft SQL Server — as in an external database — you would need to have some sort of web-service or other internet-based protocol to let you retrieve the data from the remote server.  Then you could bind the data yourself to an `ArrayList` or `Cursor`.

Alternatively, if you mean local database storage such as an SQLite DB, then it's even easier as you don't need to query over the network.

Essentially you can just follow any `ListView` tutorials as the process is pretty much the same — in your case you just want to call `Spinner.setAdapter()` rather than `ListView.setAdapter()`.

In fact, there is a [`Spinner` tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html) on the Android developers' site!

Comment: i get the data from Microsoft SQL Sever -as in an external database by using websevicess.here my my problem is i don't konw how to add that data to spinner.

Answer (score 0):

[jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) could be what you are looking for, a 100% pure java JDBC driver for Microsoft SQLServer.
Then you can implement an Adapter to retrieve the data.