# How to display particular array of items from a database (SQLServer) in a Spinner of Android?

Tags: android, spinner

How to display particular array of items from a database (Mysql) in a Spinner of Android?

Comment: Are you referring to SQLite? And your question is unclear, did you display results from a query onto a Spinner? Do you have any code?

Comment: This is an **exact** copy of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153022/how-to-display-particular-array-of-items-from-a-database-sqlserver-in-a-spinner

Answer (score 1):

Android uses SQLLite, so you could display the data from SqlLite in the spinner.  [Here is an example](http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/1c7813abe7d5a2c1) of how to do that.  Otherwise if you really need to use mysql, you would probably want to set up a web service on a server which queries the mysql database and your app could call the web service to populate the spinner.